# Variavel resetada

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Estou fazendo uma busca no anco de dados SQLITE3 dentro do meu programa e ele retorna valores pra dentro da minha variavel, entretanto quando faço uma condição a ser executada pra quando o valor é preenchido ele retorna vazio, Sou iniciante em BD Python e Kivy:

class StudentDB(BoxLayout):

```
prim_nome = ObjectProperty()
ultimo_nome = ObjectProperty()
matricula = ObjectProperty()
lista_estudante = ObjectProperty()
bix1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
select = ()

def consultadb(self):
    # Limpa lista
    del self.lista_estudante.adapter.data[:]

    # Define var select pro caso dos retornos estarem brancos ele ainda estar setado como tupla
    # Acerta texto
    self.prim_nome.text = self.prim_nome.text.capitalize()
    self.prim_nome.text = self.prim_nome.text.strip()
    self.ultimo_nome.text = self.ultimo_nome.text.capitalize()
    self.ultimo_nome.text = self.ultimo_nome.text.strip()

    # Define se os campos estão preenchidos
    if self.prim_nome.text or self.ultimo_nome.text or self.matricula.text:
        # Consulta banco de dados
        if self.prim_nome.text == '*':
            select = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM alunos2')
        elif self.prim_nome.text:
            select = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM alunos2 WHERE nome = ?', [self.prim_nome.text])
        elif self.ultimo_nome.text:
            select = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM alunos2 WHERE sobrenome = ?', [self.ultimo_nome.text])
        elif self.matricula.text:
            select = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM alunos2 WHERE mat = ?', [int(self.matricula.text)])
        # Se o retorno estiver em branco exibe critica
        # Coloquei esse print pra ver o valor retornado para a consulta e aqui ele parece preenchido
        print("Primeiro ponto variavel preenchida ")
        print(tuple(select))

        if tuple(select) == ():
            # coloquei esse print pra ver o valor retornado dentro da função e aqui ele está vazio...
            print("Segundo ponto em branco")
            print(tuple(select))
            self.bix1.add_widget(Label(text='Aluno não encontrado'))
            self.bix1.add_widget(Button(text='Ok', on_press=lambda x: popup.dismiss()))
            popup = Popup(title='Não encontrado', content=self.bix1,
                          size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 150), auto_dismiss=True)
            popup.open()
        # Se o retorno estiver ok então popula tabela com cada um dos valores retornados
        else:
            print(tuple(select))
            for i in select:
                print('entrei no for')
                dads = i
                nome_aluno = dads[1] + ' ' + dads[2]
                # incluir a informação na lista
                self.lista_estudante.adapter.data.extend([nome_aluno])
                # resetar a lista
                self.lista_estudante._trigger_reset_populate()
```

Os prints aparecem assim:

Primeiro ponto variavel preenchida 
((1, 'Filipe', 'Alves'), (3, 'Filipe', 'Ferreira'))

Segundo ponto em branco
()

Answer (score 1):

Onde tem os prints, mude para:

```
print("Primeiro ponto variavel preenchida ")
alunos = tuple(select)
print(alunos)

if len(alunos) <= 0:
```

Quando você usa `tuple(select))`, você executa o select duas vezes. Por algum motivo, seu cursor pode estar retornando em branco na segunda consulta.

Para ver se a tupla está vazia, é melhor usar o len do que `o == ()`.